# How to escape dash on oracle when updating table

Tags: oracle, special-characters

This might seem like a duplicate question at first but I've tried all the options I found and nothing works for me.

this is an example of the statement I am trying to run:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 'REER – montant minimum'
```

ON SELECT I get: `REER ¿ montant minimum`

- according to **Oracle** documentation I have 2 ways of escaping special characters:

  {}     to escape a string of characters or symbols

  \      to escape a single character or symbol (my case but I also tried {} just in case)

  ON SELECT I get:`REER \¿ montant minimum` OR `REER {¿} montant minimum`
- I have also tried SET ESCAPE ON and I get an error:

  ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
- found somewhere else and tried '||'-'||'

  needless to say, it did not work.

  ON SELECT I get: `'||'-'||'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id NUMBER,
  column_name VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 1, '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2' FROM DUAL;
```

Then if I copy/paste your update:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = 'REER – montant minimum'
WHERE  id = 1;
```

and if I type it out manually then:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = 'REER - montant minimum'
WHERE  id = 2;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id, column_name, DUMP(column_name)
FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | COLUMN_NAME              | DUMP(COLUMN_NAME)                                                                                                            
> -: | :----------------------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | REER ??? montant minimum | Typ=1 Len=30: 82,69,69,82,32,239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189,32,109,111,110,116,97,110,116,32,109,105,110,105,109,117,109
>  2 | REER - montant minimum   | Typ=1 Len=22: 82,69,69,82,32,45,32,109,111,110,116,97,110,116,32,109,105,110,105,109,117,109
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63e27e0f7aa79fff288106787f942161)*

What is the difference between `–` and `-`?

- The first is a character from the extended character set and `DUMP` outputs `239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189` (9 bytes) for that character; whereas
- The second is a character from the base ASCII character set and `DUMP` outputs `45` (1 byte) for that character.

If you want to change from one to the other then:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE( column_name, '–', '-' );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78452810ec5d491c6c0690cbe484201f)*

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you are unable to view certain characters which are not supported by your client's `NLS` settings. You need to set the client **characterset** same as that of the database.

The update statement should normally work:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
a VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO t(a) VALUES ('Hello - blah blah');
UPDATE t SET a = 'REER – montant minimum';
SELECT * FROM t;

A                                                 
------------------------
REER – montant minimum
```

If you are unable to view the characters, then your **locale-specific NLS settings** are unable to display the character. You could verify it by spooling the output to a `HTML` file and open in a browser as most browsers have globalization support:

```
sqlplus user@pass/service
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL C;\your_directory\output.html
SELECT column_name FROM table_name;
SPOOL OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
```

Now open the `output.html` file in your browser and see if the data is displayed correctly.

Comment: I get a {REER ¿ montant minimum} on select if update it like this.

Comment: @PalomaSchkrab That's because your locale-specific NLS settings are unable to display the character. See my update in the answer and follow the steps and post the output.